# Update database value after interaction with switch button. Django/HTML

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-database, sql-update

I have simple 2 state button (checkbox but looks like switch button) in Django/HTML. This button is connected with BooleanField in my Model. Connected I'm mean that when I go to the specific view (with that button) it takes from database value of BooleanField and if it's False checkbox is unchecked and if it's True checkbox is checked. The problem is that I want to create communication in other way. I mean when I change state of this button It should update value of this BooleanField in database but I have no idea how to do it.

models.py

```
class TurnOnOff(models.Model):
    turnOnOff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class TurnOnOffForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TurnOnOff
        fields = ['turnOnOff']
```

views.py

```
def getvalue(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        value = TurnOnOff.objects.first()

    else:
        value = TurnOnOff.objects.first()
    return render(request, "home.html", {'value': value})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.getvalue, name='home'),
]
```

home.html

```
   <script>
        function change(checkbox)
        {
            if (checkbox.checked)
            {
                alert("checked");
            }
            else
                alert("unchecked");
        }
    </script>

        <label class="switch">
            {% if value.turnOnOff %}
                <input id="myCheck" type="checkbox" checked="checked" onclick="change(this)">
            {% else %}
                <input id="myCheck" type="checkbox" onclick="change(this)">
            {% endif %}
            <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
```